# How I can have different events for two check boxes?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2012

I have two parts of code :

```
private void Simulink_CheckedChanged_1(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string installerfilename = path + "installer.ini";
    string installertext = File.ReadAllText(installerfilename);
    var lin = File.ReadLines(Path.Combine(path, "installer.ini")).ToArray();

    CheckBox cb = sender as CheckBox;
    if (cb.Checked)
    {
        var product = lin.Select(line => Regex.Replace(line, "product=all", "#product=all"));
        var product_tool = product.Select(line => Regex.Replace(line, "#product=Simulink", "product=Simulink"));
        File.WriteAllLines(installerfilename, product_tool);
    }
    else if (!cb.Checked)
    {
        return;
    }
}

private void  AerospaceBlockset_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string installerfilename = path + "installer.ini";
    string installertext = File.ReadAllText(installerfilename);
    var lin = File.ReadLines(Path.Combine(path, "installer.ini")).ToArray();

    CheckBox cb1 = sender as CheckBox;
    if ( cb1.Checked )
    {

        var product = lin.Select(line => Regex.Replace(line, "product=all", "#product=all"));
        var product_tool = product.Select(line => Regex.Replace(line, "#product=AerospaceBlockset", "product=AerospaceBlockset"));
        File.WriteAllLines(installerfilename, product_tool);
    }

    else if (!cb1.Checked)
    {
        return;
    }
}
```

The second one makes the same thing like first, with other words, if I check the `Simulink checkbox` or `AerospaceBlockset checkbox` or both in installer.ini file  will produce the same thing :

```
product=all => #product=all
#product=Simulink=> product=Simulink
```

To work good need to appear in `instaler.ini` file :

```
product=all => #product=all
    #product=Simulink=> product=Simulink
```

if the `Simulink checkbox` is selected and :

```
product=all => #product=all
    #product=AerospaceBlockset=> product=AerospaceBlockset
```

if the `AerospaceBlockset checkbox` is selected.

How I can do this ?

Comment: so you have two checkboxes and two checkchanged events. What is the issue/error?

Comment: He linked the first event to both checkboxes.

Answer (score 0):

You could set the tag property of both of the checkboxes to the desired string, then change the line

```
var product_tool = product.Select(line => Regex.Replace(line, "#product=AerospaceBlockset", "product=AerospaceBlockset"));
```

to

```
var product_tool = product.Select(line => Regex.Replace(line, "#product=" + ((sender as CheckBox).Tag as string), "product=" + ((sender as CheckBox).Tag as string)));
```

and finally use the same function for both of the checkboxes.

Answer (score 0):

In the constructor of your form (assuming WinForms), you can wire up the events for your checkboxes like so:

```
Simulink.CheckedChanged += Simulink_CheckedChanged_1;
AerospaceBlockset.CheckedChanged += AerospaceBlockset_CheckedChanged;
```

(You might have to remove the entries in the designer, so you don't call the methods twice.)

This way, the checkboxes will execute their respective events. Since their actions are mostly the same, you could think about extracting that logic into another method and just call that with the fitting arguments:

```
private void Simulink_CheckedChanged_1(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    ProcessIniFile("Simulink");
}
```

In `ProcessIniFile` you'd do what you're doing now in the event methods, but replace the hard coded values with the argument passed in.

Comment: you can be more explicit where in constructor?

Comment: If you're using WinForms, it really doesn't matter - as long as it's after the call to `InitializeComponents`.

Comment: ProcessIniFile it's a method ?